# QTextDocument align text after image

Tags: html, css, qt, qtextdocument

I'm using `QTextDocument` to show some data in html. I'm trying to align the text after image vertially in the center, but it seems to my doument simply ignores `style` tag. That is my html:

```
<div>
    <img src=\"plane.png\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\"/>
    <span style=\"vertical-align: middle;\">Some label</span>
</div>
```

The result can be seen in the picture. Does anyone know how to solve that problem?[image]